# Cannot call IBAction in derived class instantiated as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, inheritance

So I'm attempting to call an IBAction that is associated with the FileOwner of a subview instantiated from an xib file

I am running into a strange issue, basically I have a base class that all views inherit from:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CsoundManager.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
-(IBAction) testActionBase:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(IBAction) testActionBase:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Test Action Fired");
}

@end
```

and then I have two other view classes which inherit from this.  One is the main view that instantiates subviews.

Main View Files:
MainViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : ViewController
-(IBAction) testFireDerived:(id)sender;
@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "GlobalSequencerControlView.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    
    GlobalSequencerControlView *globalControlView = [[GlobalSequencerControlView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GlobalSequencerControls" bundle:nil];
    //self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    [self.view addSubview:globalControlView.view];
     
}

-(IBAction) testFireDerived:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Main View Fire Derived");
}

@end
```

And below are the instantiated subclass files:

GlobalSequencerControlView.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface GlobalSequencerControlView : ViewController {
    
}
-(IBAction) testFireDerived:(id)sender;
@end
```

GlobalSequencerControlView.m

```
#import "GlobalSequencerControlView.h"

@implementation GlobalSequencerControlView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(IBAction) testFireDerived:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Global Sequencer Fire Derived");
}
@end
```

When I wire up a button within the subview loaded from the xib, I am unable to get the testFireDerived IBAction found in GlobalSequencerViewController.m to execute.  The buttons are receiving the touch events as I am able to get the testActionBase method from the inherited class to fire when linked to the button.

Any thoughts/ideas as to why this is would be greatly appreciated.  The buttons seem to be receiving events but for some reason the derived actions are not being triggered even though I am wiring up the buttons to the actions in the exact same manner.

Comment: Did not get your question exactly, but if you are trying to connect the IBAction From GlobalSequencerViewController to MainViewController the action method won't show, because the button action can be given to the same viewcontroller where it is added. If you try to connect to GlobalSequencerViewController it will show you the action method. Any way let us know what you are trying to achieve so that can guide you the correct approach. But definitely the button of one VC can not be wired up with another VC

Comment: So I essentially just have two view controllers, the main one and one that is added as a subview.  The subviews button is wired up to its respective derived test action appropriately.  For some reason when I click buttons within the subview that are wired to its assigned view controller, it cannot trigger the derived actions, only the actions within the base class.  I'm wondering if maybe it has something to do with the main window being a storyboard and the subview being an xib.  Maybe the xibs File's Owner custom class is being overwritten when it's loaded by the Main View.

Comment: So if you want to trigger GlobalSequencerViewController's action, then add the "GlobalSequencerViewController" as a child view controller of MainViewController.
instead of adding it as subView of MainViewController

Comment: Wow, that solved it, thank you.  Why is it that that worked?  Does assigning a subView automatically change ownership or where events are routed?

Two days into iOS development here so pardon my ignorance lol

Comment: Cool!! Happy to hear that your issue got resolved. To make this helpful for others I added it as answer. Please accept & upvote the answer so It will be helpful for others

Comment: Please see [Creating a custom container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller?language=objc) for the correct way to add a child view controller to a container view controller.

Comment: The question was different and the answer was specific to make the button enable to fire the childVC's button action.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to trigger GlobalSequencerViewController's action, then add the "GlobalSequencerViewController" as a child view controller of MainViewController. instead of adding it as subView of MainViewController

Difference between both is as follows

> addChildViewController associates a view controller with a parent container view controller, while addSubview adds a view to the view hierarchy of the view it is being added to.

So add below mentinoed line after adding the child VC's view as subView of parent view

```
[self addChildViewController:globalControlView];
```

So the `viewDidLoad` code of MainViewController will be as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


   GlobalSequencerControlView *globalControlView = [[GlobalSequencerControlView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GlobalSequencerControls" bundle:nil];
   //self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;
   [self.view addSubview:globalControlView.view];
   [self addChildViewController:globalControlView];
   globalControlView.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [globalControlView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: That is not the correct way to setup a child view controller in a container view controller. Please see the [Creating a custom container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller?language=objc) document from Apple.

Comment: As per his/her requirement he/she needs to fire the button action of other ViewController which was getting added only as a subview, so the answer I have given will work to fire the childController's action. I did not mention "didMoveToParentVC" method and framing/constraints of childVC, etc. As the answer is specific to fire the other controller's action. Please don't be judgemental brother